# 0 as point of non-uniform convergence for $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, graphing-functions, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

I was solving a question on uniform convergence of sequences and series of functions and came across the following question:

> Show that if $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx^2}$, the sequence ${f_n}$ is not uniformly convergent in $[0,k)$ , $k>0$

Looking at the function, I could guess that something is not very right with $x=0$. This became my  suspect!

I tried using the formulation $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. f(x) is point convergent and the point-wise limit $f(x) = 0$.

This leads to : $nxe^{-x^2}$ $< \epsilon$

But I couldn't go anywhere with it. My book has provided a contradiction proof. I wanted to prove it directly. So, i plotted the function in desmos. The function shoots to infinite at x=0.

Attaching pic for reference[image: Graph]

X axis denotes the value of x, I have set the value of n as 100000 to show the case for when n tends to infinite.

How can I show this result algebraically that 0 is a point of non-uniform convergence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take $\varepsilon=1$ and $x=1/n$.  .